# Error installing rubygems

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I get the following error when trying to install rubygems version 1.3.7

```
~/Downloads/rubygems-1.3.7
$ ruby setup.rb 
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
   Permission denied - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/gem
```

Any idea what is cause this. I've previously installed RVM.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run the command

```
sudo !!
```

Comment: Clarification: `!!` represents the last command you tried to run. This is equivalent to `sudo ruby setup.rb`.

Comment: This works, but I think the error is actually due to the fact that i haven't installed Xcode yet...

Answer (score 1):

Rather than mess with your system installation of Ruby, consider using [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) to manage your [Ruby installation(s)](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rubies/installing/). RVM will install multiple Rubies on demand, allow you to create various [gem sets](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/gemsets/creating/), copy them between versions of Ruby, all while sandboxing your Ruby installation in `~/.rvm`.

[Installing RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/)

Comment: @Ben, did you follow all the RVM installation steps, including adding the script to your shell's `~/.bashrc` or similar file, and restart your shell? Also, did you do a `rvm install` for a Ruby so there is something in your sandbox to work with? It sounds like you're running into path issues. Please add the output to `echo $PATH`, `which ruby` and `gem env` to your original question.